# Access global Method of Global Class in Static Method

Tags: java, android, global-variables, global, static-methods

I have created one Static Method in one of my class and in the same static method I want to access the method of my Global Class, if I am creating the class by -

```
final GlobalClass globaVariable = (GlobalClass)getApplicationContext();
```

then it is showing me error and suggesting me to make this object static and if I am making this object static then I am not getting the values from my global class and method as it's creating the fresh copy. Please suggest me that how can I get the access the global method in static method.

My Global Method is as bellow :

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

    private int vMyToken;
    private String vConCmpName;
    private boolean vUserLoginMode;
    private String vGlobalSessionID;
    private String vglobalAccInternalID;


    public int getToken() {

        return vMyToken;
    }

    public void setToken(int myTokenVal) {

        //Toast.makeText(GlobalClass.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        vMyToken = myTokenVal;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add to question code of `Toast` class, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to convert the instance variables in GlobalClass to static and also make the method in GlobalClass static. As the variables are  static only a single copy will be maintained and the static method can access these variables.

```
private static int vMyToken;
private static String vConCmpName;
private static boolean vUserLoginMode;
private static String vGlobalSessionID;
private static String vglobalAccInternalID;
```